# Discord on_reaction_add error Unknown Role

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

i want to create a bot, who will get user a role via reaction.
The code seems to be working but i get an error in console.
But i get an error.

```
Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "slh.py", line 47, in on_reaction_add
    await user.add_roles(user, newrole)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 223, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "slh.py", line 47, in on_reaction_add
    await user.add_roles(user, newrole)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 223, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

I don't know why i get this error. Because the role "testrole" is exist in my discord. I have try to use discord.utils.get withe name="channelname" and with id="723xxxxx". Both brings the same error.

The Bot has all privilegs/rights on discord.
Who can help me to fix this issue ?

Here is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == '✅':
      newrole = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="testrole")
      await user.add_roles(user, newrole)
```

Hope someone can help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's trying to add `user` as a role. You can simply delete that, you do not need to pass it in as an argument as you are already calling the function from the class. Use this instead:

```py
await user.add_roles(newrole)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late answer. i am a little busy. :)
I have change the line. Now i get a new error.

'''
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
'''

Comment: The bot have an own role called 'testbot'. the role have all rights (incl. administrator and manage roles).
i cant understand why python says missing permission.

any idea ?

Comment: @loser09 I have edited my answer, it should be fixed now.